# I have a problem with bloc pattern and change notifier

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-provider

I apply the same bloc pattern in the login and signup form,when i have only one provider, is not a problem. But now i implement second provider. This provider controller a page view, the index and other parameters. The problem is that i implement multiprovider, when i start login page i have an error.This is my code.

```html
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //final _prefs = new PreferenciasUsuario();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => new UiProvider()),
        Provider(create: (_) => new BlocFormProvider())
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demos',
          initialRoute: 'init',
          routes: {
            'init': (BuildContext context) => InitialPage(),
            'login': (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
            'signup': (BuildContext context) => SignUpPage(),
            'home': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
            'remember': (BuildContext context) => RememberPasswordPage(),
            'start': (BuildContext context) => StartPage()
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my bloc provider

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'login_bloc.dart';

class BlocFormProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  static BlocFormProvider _instancia;

  factory BlocFormProvider({Key key, Widget child}) {
    if (_instancia == null) {
      _instancia = new BlocFormProvider._internal(key: key, child: child);
    }
    return _instancia;
  }

  final loginBloc = LoginBloc();

  BlocFormProvider._internal({Key key, Widget child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;

  static LoginBloc of(BuildContext context) {
    return context
        .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<BlocFormProvider>()
        .loginBloc;
  }
}
```

Finally this is the error:

```
The getter 'loginBloc' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: loginBloc
The relevant error-causing widget was LoginPage
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why your `LoginBloc` is wrapped inside `InheritedWidget`? Do you use BLoC library? If yes, why not use BlocProvider/MultiBlocProvider?